# Property is assumed atomic by default

Tags: objective-c, properties, compiler-errors, llvm, compiler-warnings

I'm trying to get rid of an annoying warning that CLANG/LLVM 3.0 is giving me. I have the following ivar set in my object:

```
bool preloaded;
```

And the following property declaration:

```
@property(readonly) bool preloaded;
```

And the following synthesize call:

```
@synthesize preloaded;
```

As it stands, the compiler complains:

> Property is assumed atomic by default

If I change the property declaration to add "atomic":

```
@property(atomic,readonly) bool preloaded;
```

It complains about that, too:

> error: expected a property attribute before 'atomic'

So it appears I'm damned if I do and damned if I don't... Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Well, `atomic` isn't a valid attribute keyword, so it makes sense that the second bit causes an error. Dunno about the first, though.

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured, but seeing as how Xcode syntax highlights "atomic", I figured that maybe they'd added it as a valid attribute keyword.

Comment: I tried `@property (atomic,readonly) bool preloaded;` and it compiles fine. It removes the warning too. I'm using Xcode 4.2.1.

Comment: the keyword "atomic" works in some cases but not in others. I haven't been able to isolate the how and where, but in certain cases it will compile the module fine, but will fail if another module references the header file. And if I take the failing property and copy it to a new class, it suddenly compiles fine again. This really is starting to look like a bug in LLVM.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems you have the **Implicit Atomic Objective-C Properties** LLVM compiler warning enabled in your project settings. Turning this off will remove the warning.

As noted above, `atomic` is not a valid keyword, and is merely implied by the absence of `nonatomic`. From Apple's [Declared Properties documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html):

> You can use this attribute to specify that accessor methods are not atomic. (There is no keyword to denote atomic.)

Comment: I'll mark this as "correct" since disabling the setting gets rid of the warning, but I'm still puzzled over why those properties were flagged to begin with. Is it a bug in LLVM? I'd be far happier if I could just keep all warnings enabled...

Comment: Warnings are more than just a game of satisfying the compiler, they serve as a reminder to the developer to be aware of certain behaviours while programming. To keep the warning enabled but disable this instance, see [Controlling Static Analyzer Diagnostics](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#diagnostics) in the Clang documentation.

Comment: Awesome! That worked like a charm! I can now compile with all warnings except pedantic (due to my use of ##__VA_ARGS__ for logging)